# SIP Proxy 401 Response Handling

Tags: proxy, sip, state-machine, digest-authentication

I am hoping to get some clarification on the expected behavior of a SIP Proxy when proxying 401 responses from a downstream UAS.

Our SIP Proxy is configured to proxy requests downstream in a round-robin fashion.  If the downstream UAS responds to an INVITE with a 401, I would expect the SIP Proxy to keep enough state to select this same UAS as the target when the originating upstream UAC sends the second INVITE containing authentication credentials.

Instead, what I'm seeing is that the SIP Proxy will proxy the 401 response, receive the ACK from the upstream UAC, and immediately destroy all state pertaining to this dialog.  Then when the upstream UAC sends the second INVITE with authentication credentials the SIP Proxy will forward that request in round-robin fashion.  If we get lucky then the SIP Proxy will select the same UAS for the second INVITE, but most of the time it will select some other downstream target.

I'm new to SIP and I've been reading RFC 3261 to try and understand what the correct behavior should be, but I'm not seeing an obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are really asking is an understanding of how further requests within a dialog work.  For that you need to understand the "Record-Route" / "Route" headers.

It really doesn't mater what the response code is, the next request in the dialog will go directly to the remote URI unless (and there almost always is) a route set provided.

From section 12 of RFC 3261:

> The route set is the list of servers that need to be traversed to
>   send a request to the peer.

From section 16.6 Request Forwarding

> ```
>   4. Record-Route
>
>      If this proxy wishes to remain on the path of future requests
>      in a dialog created by this request (assuming the request
>      creates a dialog), it MUST insert a Record-Route header field
>      value into the copy before any existing Record-Route header
>      field values, even if a Route header field is already present.
> ```

From 20.34 Route

> The Route header field is used to force routing for a request
>   through    the listed set of proxies.  Examples of the use of the
>   Route header    field are in Section 16.12.1.

From 12.1.2 UAC Behavior

> The route set MUST be set to the list of URIs in the Record-Route
>   header field from the response, taken in reverse order and preserving 
>   all URI parameters.  If no Record-Route header field is present in
>   the response, the route set MUST be set to the empty set.  This route 
>   set, even if empty, overrides any pre-existing route set for future
>   requests in this dialog.

From 16.12 Summary of Proxy Route Processing

> In the absence of local policy to the contrary, the processing a
>   proxy performs on a request containing a Route header field can be
>   summarized in the following steps.
>
> ```
>   1.  The proxy will inspect the Request-URI.  If it indicates a
>       resource owned by this proxy, the proxy will replace it with
>       the results of running a location service.  Otherwise, the
>       proxy will not change the Request-URI.
>
>   2.  The proxy will inspect the URI in the topmost Route header
>       field value.  If it indicates this proxy, the proxy removes it
>       from the Route header field (this route node has been
>       reached).
>
>   3.  The proxy will forward the request to the resource indicated
>       by the URI in the topmost Route header field value or in the
>       Request-URI if no Route header field is present.  The proxy
>       determines the address, port and transport to use when
>       forwarding the request by applying the procedures in [4] to
>       that URI.
> ```

See this [example](http://www.in2eps.com/fo-sip/tk-fo-sip-dialog.html) for how it works.

So basically the initial request should build up "Route-Set" that is then used to generate the "Route" header in the following request.

So for your problem, it sounds like either the "Route-Set" is not being built up and/or being sent back in the response or the UAC isn't using the remote target and route set to build the Request-URI and Route headers correctly for the next request.

There is also the difference between [strict and loose routing](http://www.iptel.org/sip/intro/scenarios/rr/strict_vs_loose) which also may be in play here as well.  I would assume you would be using lr tho.

Comment: You are correct that no record-route or route headers are being inserted anywhere in the exchange.  However, I'm wondering why this would be required.  Record-route is only inserted by proxies, so if the next hop after the proxy is not another proxy but the remote URI instead (like if the proxy is just a load balancer) then it will definitely not be listed in the record-route headers.  The proxy will still need to remember the previous choice to properly handle the second INVITE.

I noticed that the second INVITE doesn't have the "to-tag" from the first INVITE, so maybe this is related?

Comment: Adding a Record-Route is operational.  So for proxies that can be "dropped" out of the loop, then yes they will not add a record-route in.  It's hard to know who's at fault here.  You could say it's the sip proxy for not adding in a Record-Route, you could blame the main proxy processing the invite.  If authentication is implemented "nicely" then it wouldn't matter what proxy gets the INVITE, it should be able to verify if it passes authentication successfully or not.

Comment: There is also the problem that if the request is signed then you can't modify the request unless you resign it. So the proxy in the middle would have to be stateless or know how to authenticate the request.